# how do you do it so that when the website is opened the WhatsApp chat pop up will automatically appear

Tags: javascript, html, css

i took this code from [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tokydev/ozph4m1v/) I want to change pop ups to open automatically when web pages are accessed

```js
$(function() {
  $('#WAButton').floatingWhatsApp({
    phone: '1231231231', //WhatsApp Business phone number International format-
    //Get it with Toky at https://toky.co/en/features/whatsapp.
    headerTitle: 'Chat with us on WhatsApp!', //Popup Title
    popupMessage: 'Hello, how can we help you?', //Popup Message
    showPopup: true, //Enables popup display
    buttonImage: '<img src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/rafaelbotazini/floating-whatsapp/3d18b26d5c7d430a1ab0b664f8ca6b69014aed68/whatsapp.svg" />', //Button Image
    //headerColor: 'crimson', //Custom header color
    //backgroundColor: 'crimson', //Custom background button color
    position: "right"    
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!--Jquery-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--Floating WhatsApp css-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawcdn.githack.com/rafaelbotazini/floating-whatsapp/3d18b26d5c7d430a1ab0b664f8ca6b69014aed68/floating-wpp.min.css">
<!--Floating WhatsApp javascript-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/rafaelbotazini/floating-whatsapp/3d18b26d5c7d430a1ab0b664f8ca6b69014aed68/floating-wpp.min.js"></script>



<body>
<!--Div where the WhatsApp will be rendered-->
  <div id="WAButton"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the following snippet to the object passed into the floatingWhatsApp function

```
autoOpenTimeout:1,
```

for your case,

```
 $(function() {
      $('#WAButton').floatingWhatsApp({
        phone: '1231231231', //WhatsApp Business phone number International format-
        headerTitle: 'Chat with us on WhatsApp!', //Popup Title
        popupMessage: 'Hello, how can we help you?', //Popup Message
        showPopup: true, //Enables popup display
        buttonImage: '<img src="https://rawcdn.githack.com/rafaelbotazini/floating-whatsapp/3d18b26d5c7d430a1ab0b664f8ca6b69014aed68/whatsapp.svg" />', //Button Image
        position: "right", 
        autoOpenTimeout:1,

      });
    });
```

Use this for your reference:
[https://github.com/rafaelbotazini/floating-whatsapp#:~:text=autoopentimeout](https://github.com/rafaelbotazini/floating-whatsapp#:%7E:text=autoopentimeout)